# Which library to use for session in javamail api

Tags: java, android, email, jakarta-mail, libraries

I am setting up my app to use JavaMail API. I don't want to get into details, I just want to implement it in my app.

[Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API without using the default/built-in app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/3319521)

So while importing the libraries in `GMailSender.java`, I am stuck on `Session`.

There are many options:
[image: This picture shows all the options]

So from the options in this picture, which one should I select?

Answer (score 0):

Since your `GMailSender.java` extends `javax.mail.Authenticator`, you can just pass `this` for session, e.g

```
Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);
```

And the `Session` must be imported from `javax.mail.Session`

Comment: Use [Session.getInstance](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes), and make sure you're using the official [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed javax.mail is not correctly imported, please click **Sync project with Gradle Files** which is in `File` menu.
In fact the Session class uses:

```
import javax.mail.Session;
```